# how to update batches in Mysql for large number of rows

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I saw previous answers regarding updating rows in batches , but none of them worked in Mysql; I have more than 8 million row to update and I saw that the best way is to divide them into batches ,I also saw the answer of T-sql:

```
Declare @Rowcount INT = 1;

WHILE (@Rowcount > 0)   
BEGIN
        UPDATE TOP (100000) [table]   --<-- define Batch Size in TOP Clause
           SET [New_ID] = [Old_ID]
        WHERE [New_ID] <> [Old_ID]

        SET @Rowcount = @@ROWCOUNT;

       CHECKPOINT;   --<-- to commit the changes with each batch
END
```

can someone make the same for mysql ? or implement what Im thinking of:
I need to start with row 1 , and update rows from row 1 to 1000 , then from 1001 to 2000, etc ...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use [INSERT ... SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html) with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE option. The operation will check if the key already exists in the target table and if yes it will perform the specified update.

The key point here is to thoroughly formulate the SELECT statement, especially its order as you plan to do it in batches.

Comment: but the question was I need to update my rows in batches , but there is no such implementation in mysql , your answer is like normal update , for big data it will take alot of time .Thanks for replying

Comment: the problem is that there is no (to my knowledge) clear batch update statement. So, you have to use a workaround. INSERT ... SELECT  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is one of them. Working from some client (e.g. node.js) is also possible to use LOAD DATA with REPLACE option.